# Kohana 3.3 Routing with subfolders working on Windows but failed on Linux

Tags: kohana-3.3

I use kohana 3.3 (https://github.com/koseven/koseven) and have added this controllers:

```
applications/classes/Controller/Myfolder/Subfolder1
applications/classes/Controller/Myfolder/Subfolder2
applications/classes/Controller/Myfolder/Subfolder3
```

Each folder includes few controllers:

```
applications/classes/Controller/Myfolder/Subfolder1/Mycontroller1.php
applications/classes/Controller/Myfolder/Subfolder1/Mycontroller2.php
applications/classes/Controller/Myfolder/Subfolder1/Mycontroller3.php
```

In Windows this routing working fine, but on Linux thats not working and show 404:

```
Route::set('mycontroller', '<directory>/<controller>/<action>', array(
    'directory' => 'myfolder/subfolder1|myfolder/subfolder2|myfolder/subfolder3',
));
```

I must create a route for every controller like:

```
Route::set('myfolder/subfolder1', 'myfolder/subfolder1/<controller>/<action>')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'Myfolder/Subfolder1',
));
Route::set('myfolder/subfolder2', 'myfolder/subfolder2/<controller>/<action>')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'Myfolder/Subfolder2',
));
```

What is my mistake on Linux? And no, its not help to uppercase to this (thats not working on Windows and Linux, its must be lowercase):

```
Route::set('mycontroller', '<directory>/<controller>/<action>', array(
    'directory' => 'Myfolder/Subfolder1|Myfolder/Subfolder2|Myfolder/Subfolder3',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux is case sensitive filesystem.

`<direcotry>` shouldn't contains `/`. Try use [Cascading Filesystem](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide/kohana/files/classes) and `myfolder_subfolder1` or [route filters](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide/kohana/routing#route-filters) to change case in `direcotry`